# repaint in java not working

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I am trying to draw a rectangle which its position is updated every second, for that I have a class which extends JPanel and in it I have overriden the paint ( or paintComponent) function_ I have tried both _ but apparanetly this function is called only once and as it is shown in the code below when I try to call it in an infinite loop with repaint function it doesnt get called, any ideas what I can do?

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
 public  void setUpBoard(){
     JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     Board board = new Board();
     frame.setVisible(true);
     frame.setResizable(false);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setSize(600, 600);
     frame.setLocation(350, 80);
     frame.add(board);
     }
 public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(food.getX(),200,20,20);
       }
}
```

the code above is the graphic part, below is the main function, which is placed in another class :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Board board = new Board();
    FoodGenerator food = new FoodGenerator();
    board.setUpBoard();
    while(true){
        board.repaint();
        food.adder();
        try {
            sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

in the code above food.adder is where the position of the rectangle is updated, which I have checked and doesnt have any issues.

Comment: Are you changing anything between calls to repaint? I would check if the food object in your main is the same one as the food in your paint method.

Comment: Don't override `paint`, use `paintComponent`; Don't break the paint chain, make sure you are are calling `super.paintComponent`; Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for a better understanding into how painting works.  Also, take a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for a better understand into how a Swing GUI works

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and for simplicity, [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're creating a new `Board` object in `setUpBoard` and adding *that* to your JFrame:

```
Board board = new Board();
// ...
frame.add(board);
```

So when you use `repaint()`, you're repainting the instance of `Board` that you created in the `main` method, and not the instance you created in `setUpBoard`, which is the one you add to the frame.

This can be easily fixed by using `Board board = this;` in `setUpBoard`, or, even simpler in my opinion, just using `frame.add(this)`. Subsequent calls to `repaint` will then schedule a call to `paint` for the same Board object that you created in the main method.

Also, since you're working with Swing, don't use `paint`, and instead use `paintComponent`, making sure that `super.paintComponent(g)` is the first statement in the method body.

Comment: IMHO the `Board` shouldn't be creating the frame, but it doesn't effect your answer

Answer (score 0):

Another problem is that the repaint calls are being done on the main thread, not on the event thread.